# Issues with threading in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf

I want this method to be threaded out so I can set a timer and not wait for it to finish. It's a call to a service.

```
private static void callValueEng(ValueEngineService.Contracts.ValueEngServiceParams param)
{
    using (WCFServiceChannelFactory<IValueEngineService> client =
              new WCFServiceChannelFactory<IValueEngineService>(
                  Repository.Instance.GetWCFServiceUri(typeof(IValueEngineService))))
    {
        client.Call(x => x.ValueManyTransactionsWithOldEngines(translatedParams));
    }
}
```

I tried threading it out like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread newThread;
//RestartValueEngineService();

List<TransactionInfo> currentIdsForValuation = ((counter + 7000) <= allIds.Count) 
                              ? allIds.GetRange(counter, 7000) 
                              : allIds.GetRange(counter, allIds.Count - counter);
translatedParams.tranquoteIds = currentIdsForValuation;

// thread this out
newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(callValueEng(translatedParams));
```

But it's saying 'the best overloaded match has some invalid arguments.' What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
var invoker = new Action<ValueEngineService.Contracts.ValueEngServiceParams>(callValueEng);
invoker.BeginInvoke(translatedParams, null, null);
```

this will asynchronously call your method.

Comment: How do I pass it the argument?

Comment: Fixed it, made a mistake (overlooked the parameter)

Comment: All we needed was async though, so it worked out anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: Remember, you need to call EndInvoke when you BeginInvoke, otherwise you could potentially be introducing a leak.

Comment: @slandau : In this way your application could hands because BeginInvoke will pupm UI thread messages pool... I would suggest to run thsi code in the dedicated thread anyway

Comment: @slandau : ...assuming you are running BeginInvoke() from the UI thread

Comment: This is running on a service and we are restarting the service on a timer so the invoke shouldn't leak.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Threading.Thread constructor takes a delegate as it's parameter.
Try

```
newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(callValueEng));
newThread.start(translatedParams);
```

Comment: This won't work because I guess my method is in the incorrect form.

Comment: The issue is that your method is static.  The thread constructor takes a delegate that maps to a method with the signature void method(obj params).  Since it's static, use the invoker answer posted.

Comment: @tafoo85 : You can pass static method with right signature to the Thread.Start(...), the problem is OP's method has wrong signature

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor in System.Threading.Thread class which take delegate of the type you have passed. you can only pass threadstart or paramererizedthreadstart type delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question "What am I doing wrong?" - you trying to pass method with signature which is not supported by `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx))

signature should be

```
 void ParameterizedThreadStart(Object obj)
```

and not the

```
void ParameterizedThreadStart(
                    ValueEngineService.Contracts.ValueEngServiceParams param)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .NET 4? If so, you can do this:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => callValueEng(translatedParams));
```

And it will run your code on a new thread. If you need to do something when it completes, then you can easily do that too:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => callValueEng(translatedParams))
    .ContinueWith(() => /* Some Other Code */);
```